# Erorr calculating sum of squared difference

Tags: python, numpy, image-processing

Assume that I have two image, image 1 and templete as image 2. I want to Implementing sum of squared difference between the image (M, N) and a template matching, to find the matched area of the image as rectangle. I have this code for calculating SSD, but when I try to use my input images it gives an error of: value error: mismatch in the length of stride and shape,

```
def sumsqdiff3(input_image, template):
    window_size = template.shape
    y = as_strided(input_image,
                    shape=(input_image.shape[0] - window_size[0] + 1,
                           input_image.shape[1] - window_size[1] + 1,) +
                          window_size,
                    strides=input_image.strides * 2)
    y = as_strided(input_image,
               shape=(input_image.shape[0] - window_size[0] + 1,
                      input_image.shape[1] - window_size[1] + 1),
               strides=input_image.strides * 2)
    ssd = np.einsum('ijkl,kl->ij', y, template)
    ssd *= - 2
    ssd += np.einsum('ijkl, ijkl->ij', y, y)
    ssd += np.einsum('ij, ij', template, template)

    return ssd
```

Here is the link to original and templete images:

https://ibb.co/bsgY71Z

https://ibb.co/C869x9F

I want to find the ear of cameraman in the original image using SSD method. A rectangle showing the ear of the man in the image.

How do I solve this error and draw a rectangle around the area of the match?

https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided.html

Comment: Please offer us a [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). You might produce simple synthetic images of a triangle and a noisy triangle, to demonstrate calling sumsqdiff3().

Comment: Normally we'd expect to see a full error message, with traceback.  But the only thing that could raise an error about `value error: mismatch in the length of stride and shape` is one of the `as_strided` calls.  And the problem should be obvious - there's a mismatch in the length of the stride and shape argument tuples.  `as_strided` is an advanced function that should be used with caution, and careful testing.

Comment: @hpaulj, is there any inbuild function in opencv or python that does the job? It is not nessary for me to write things from scratch.

Answer (score 0):

You have two `y=` lines.

The second one is obviously impossible. You give a bidimensional shape. So `y` is a 2D-array, as `input_image` is. But have a strides that has 2 times more dimensions as `input_image` has. That is obviously a nonsense.

The first one is impossible also. But less obviously so. Because your "templete" is a RGBA color image (so a 3D-array), and image a 2D array (b&w image). So the shape of `y` is a 5d shape. Namely, since your image is (490,487) and template (27,27,4), would be (464,461,27,27,4). And the strides, for `float64` for example, and assuming that inputs are contiguous image, with contiguous strides, would be (3896,8,3896,8)

So 5 shape 4 strides, hence the error. It makes no sense to have 5 axis for the shape, but 4 axis for the strides. You need one size (shape) and one stride for each axis.

Problem is obviously that you expected the template to be a 2d b&w image also.

If it were, then the first `y` makes sense. `y` is, for each pixel, far enough from the border to be able to extract a sliding 27x27 windows from the image (hence the `- template.shape[0]+1` and the like), a 2d array that is this sliding window. So a 4d array. Whose shape is (W-26, H-26, 27, 27).

And strides of `y` is just the stride of the input image, repeated. Meaning that traveling along axis 0 (along the rows of the image), but also along axis 2 (along the row of the sliding windows) is just the same travel as traveling along axis 0 of `input_image`. And like wise for axis 1 and 3 of y.

That code works as intended (that is, it doesn't crash, doesn't complain about inconsistency, neither in the `as_strided` line, nor in the `einsum` and other arithmetics operations on `y`.

Of course, it doesn't give the result you expect, and you are far from being able to draw a red square from this. If it were that easy, us, computer vision expert, would be unemployed :D.
But, from a SO point on view, that is from a coding point of view, it does implement the algorithm you wanted to implement. Just, that algorithm isn't that magical. See (the darker, the better, since it is a difference)

[image]

Unless the template is really extracted from the image directly (`template=input_image[100:127,200:227]`) it never really works to just compare pixel by pixel the absolute values. And even then... we do see the dark spot at  the ear position. But it is not the only one. And I am just comparing the image with a part of itself here...

[image]

a cosine similarity would probably be more realistic. But even that still doesn't just show the ear and nothing else: (the brighter the better here, since it is a cosine)

[image]

But that is another question. For your question, what matters is: you need `templete` to be a b&w image, not a color one.

Comment: I came accross this function in opencv, which does templete matching "cv2.TM_SQDIFF". I wonder if it is based on "sum of squared difference" method? it takes images as gray scale, I wonder why do we need to convert to gray? is it wrong if we do templete matching using color images?

Comment: Yes, it is the exact same thing. And, cosine similarity, that you can get with `(y*template[None,None,:,:]).sum(axis=(2,3)) / np.linalg.norm(y, axis=(2,3) / np.linalg.norm(template)`, is the same as `cv2.TM_CCORR_NORMED`.

Comment: I am intersted in "sum of squared difference" so does  "cv2.TM_SQDIFF" do the job? I do not know why you mentioned cv2.TM_CCORR_NORMED, I do not need that. Thanks